# jquery ajax append image src attr with a variable and wait for server response before appending

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, image, variables

What's the syntax for appending image scr + variable.

```
$('#FBProfileImgVar').attr('src', 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture?type=large' );
```

The above shows "undefined" at a place where it's suppose to be a variable

Edit 1. Maybe the problem lies with ajax, how do i make the above line of code to wait until response is present before appending?

Comment: Assuming response.id exists and is set, then your code looks ok

Comment: it seems just fine, I'm interested in your ajax call & result

Comment: That code looks perfectly valid. The problem most likely lies in another piece of code. Perhaps the `response` variable does not contain what you expect it to.

Comment: "undefined" `response.id`or what?

Comment: @mplungjan without assuming, how do i make sure that + response.id + is present before .append fires?

Comment: Use `if (response.authResponse) { // YOUR Code }` to check if user has logged into your app and gave permissions needed

Comment: @user2944805 - my downvote is for a lack of initial debugging. Did you see what the contents of `response.id` was before posting this question?

Comment: [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8uSjj/) - your code works correctly. As I said before, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Lix yes reponse.id is a facebook id as i have it working somewhere else, anyway i just wanted to know your reason, and yes it does work, it's because the src is appended before response.id is present, i need to solve that. Thanks.

Comment: Your question title does not reflect the actual question at all. Please update your post to include information about the actual ajax call and the problems you are actually facing. Right now, the important part of your question only appears in the edit you added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using response.id use **`response.authResponse.userID`** to get User ID

Example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {

       console.log(response.authResponse.userID); // debugg!

        $('#FBProfileImgVar').attr('src', 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.authResponse.userID + '/picture?type=large' );

        } else {

           alert('User canceled login or did not fully authorize the app.');

             }
    });
```

[Demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/QEqwh/)
[Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/QEqwh/1)

Comment: changing response.id to response.authResponse.userID worked well, thanks, edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You said it was working if you entered a number, so just an idea came to my mind, of what could be wrong:

if you are using

```
var response.id = 4;
```

it wouldn't work. **http://jsfiddle.net/8uSjj/1/**

the var may not contain the char "."

```
var responseid = 4;
```

it would work **http://jsfiddle.net/8uSjj/2/**

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works but since it's predefined, it doesn't serve the purpose of the above question. If this was the case, it would have done this.  $('#FBProfileImgVar').attr('src', 'https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large' );